# VS2008 project only compiles 1 C++ file in x64 target

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, compilation, 64-bit

This is very strange, as mostly it compiles everything well, but this one project (the main DLL project, which links in many library projects) just refuses.  It compiles only CK20_Test.cpp, then proceeds to link.  If I exclude that one, it compiles only DebugInfo.cpp and links.  Et cetera.

If I switch to Win32 target, it compiles all fine.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM, 
Microsoft .NET Framework,
Version 3.5 SP1,
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008   91605-130-0691883-60531

and a bunch of standard hotfixes installed.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: XMD, Configuration: DebugR x64 ------
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'XMD', configuration 'DebugR|x64'
1>Compiling...
1>stdafx.cpp
1>Compiling manifest to resources...
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>Linking...
1>LINK : D:\prj\alpha\64\shared\x64\DebugR\XMDCore.dll not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>Embedding manifest...
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>Build log was saved at "file://d:\prj\alpha\64\shared\xmd\x64\DebugR\BuildLog.htm"
1>XMD - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Edit: configured another computer.  Same problem.  I feel like the project file must be broken (see my comment below on content), or the compiler is messed up.  But I can't imagine what I would do to unbreak it.

Comment: Can you post the console output from your build? Or your build log?

Comment: Rebuild (project-only) log appended.

Comment: You said it compiles CK20_Test.cpp, but I don't see it in the build log...

Comment: "DebugR" is quite unusual.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Try opening the vcproj file in a text editor -- you may have some options that are set differently in the 64-bit configuration

Comment: Hans, exactly the same problem with Release configuration.  DebugR is a copy of Release with debug symbols on and optimization off.  I find it's more useful than the normal debug configuration.

Comment: These are all the differences from the Win32 configuration:
Name="DebugR|x64"
  OutputDirectory="$(SolutionDir)$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)"
    IntermediateDirectory="$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)"

TargetEnvironment="3"

DebugInformationFormat="3"

AdditionalLibraryDirectories= (omitted)

TargetMachine="17"

Comment: Luchian, I said it compiles only one file.  I disabled CK20_Test.cpp, and it chose a different file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
The C++ Output Files Object File Name setting (/Fo) was $(IntDir).

When I compile in x64, the program generated DebugR.obj.
In Win32 compilers, the same setting produced DebugR\$(InputName).obj.

Likewise for Release or Debug configuration.

Solution: Change $(IntDir) to $(IntDir)\